# \AtBeginDocument / \subfigure: TeX Live 2020 issue

Tags: distributions

I have a file (`test.tex`) which content is:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{This caption should disappeard...}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and produces the layout:

[image]

Until Tex Live 2019 I used to run the command:

```bash
pdflatex "\AtBeginDocument{\def\caption#1{}} \nonstopmode \input{test.tex}"
```

to obtain a figure without the caption:

[image]

But with TeX Live 2020 it doesn't work anymore. The `.pdf` file produced still contains the caption. It happens when packages like `subcaption` are called.

Is there a way to obtain the same result with TeX Live 2020?

Comment: Works for me with an updated TL 2020... Run the example with `pdflatex "\listfiles\DebugHooksOn\AtBeginDocument{\def\caption#1{}} \nonstopmode \input{test.tex}"` then upload the log to https://pastebin.com/ (or similar), please

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, this is the TeX Live 2020 log: https://pastebin.com/8CABV4vv

Comment: This is the Tex Live 2019 one: https://pastebin.com/26inparP

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, is this a question addressed to me?

Comment: your texlive 2020 format is not up to date (it is showing February not October release)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I simply ran what Phelype Oleinik asked in the first comment.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi ah Ok, Phelype was assuming you had an up to date texlive 2020

Comment: `tlmgr update --self --all` should update your texlive (possibly needing `sudo` depending how it was installed)

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Yes, I asked for that command to have some debugging from `lthooks` because I assumed your TL was up-to-date (it's not).  As David said, updating should solve the problem.  The culprit is that your version of `caption` delays defining `\caption` to `\AtBeginDocument`, which happens after your redefinition.  If you don't want to update you can (but I _really_ don't recommend you to) build with `pdflatex "\edef\documentclass{\unexpanded{\RequirePackage{etoolbox}\AfterEndPreamble{\def\caption#1{}}}\unexpanded\expandafter{\documentclass}} \nonstopmode \input{test.tex}"`

Comment: By the way, I can reproduce the problem with an updated TeX Live 2019, so I guess yours isn't updated as well

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik the `\AfterEndPreamble` solution doesn't work. I'm trying to update my texlive... but neither the solution with `sudo` nor the one without sudo work: https://pastebin.com/nQmMD8Zm (I never updated my texlive versions)

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Sorry, I posted a comment which I then realised it didn't work.  I deleted and posted a new one. Regarding updating: try `sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) /usr/local/texlive`, then `tlmgr update --self --all` again

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, Both solutions work. If you like you can report it into an answer to my question so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your log (which was actually the terminal session, which contains far less information than the actual `.log` file):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
```

which tells you you have TeX Live 2020 from February, and also

```
subcaption.sty    2020/01/22 v1.3d Sub-captions (AR)
 caption.sty    2020/01/03 v3.4h Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2020/01/03 v1.8h caption3 kernel (AR)
```

which are also from the beginning of the year.

The problem is that that version of `caption.sty` defines `\caption` `\AtBeginDocument`, which then happens after your command-line redefinition.  You can either update (recommended) or use a later hook to redefine `\caption`.

---

To update TeXLive you only need to run (maybe with `sudo` if you installed with root):

```bash
tlmgr update --all --self
```

(`--all` tells it to update all packages; you can replace it by a list of packages to update; use `tlmgr update --list` to see packages that have update candidates.  `--self` tells `tlmgr` to update itself if needed).  In your particular case, for some reason `sudo tlmgr` doesn't work, so you can try changing the ownership of the `texlive` folder with `sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) /usr/local/texlive` (`$(whoami)` expands to your user name).

---

To work around that you need to use a hook later than `\AtBeginDocument` (unless you had a newer LaTeX, then you could use `lthooks` and all would be much easier).

The best way would be to add a `\csname mycommandline\endcsname` after `\begin{document}`, then build with:

```bash
$ pdflatex "\def\mycommandline{\def\caption##1{}} \input{test.tex}"
```

However, assuming you don't want to change your document (I do *not* recommend doing this!) you can use `\AfterEndPreamble`, provided by `etoolbox`, but since you are loading from the command line you can't load a package, otherwise TeX sets `\jobname` (opens the `.log`) and your document will be saved into `texput.pdf`.  So you need a hook to delay loading `etoolbox` to delay redefining `\caption` (see the complication?).  You can hook into `\documentclass` (don't):

```bash
pdflatex "\edef\documentclass{\unexpanded{\RequirePackage{etoolbox}\AfterEndPreamble{\def\caption#1{}}}\unexpanded\expandafter{\documentclass}} \input{test.tex}"
```